# install webpack on macOs with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I want to install webpack with npm:

```
sudo npm install -g webpack
```

and this is my error:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@11.10.1 (node-v67 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib' 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v11.10.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:984:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v11.10.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

however i use sudo and clear my catch but still i have this error.

Comment: did you install npm thru their installer or thru nvm?

Comment: i think  installed npm thru installer

Comment: like the other guy answered, use nvm instead of their installer. their installer doesnt really handle permissions well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Remove `Node.js` from your system and all the `node_modules`. You can find more details on how to do that [in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)
- Make sure everything is deleted by calling `which node` and `node -v`. These commands should give you an error (which is what we're going for here).
- Install [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Then install `Node.js` using `nvm`.
- **Never call `nvm`, `node` or `npm` with `sudo`**. This will *"lock"* your modules and restrict them to the `sudo` user and cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: Bonus points for mentioning to never use sudo on those, caused me a lot of pain in the past.